Firewalld cuts the maximum download speed
I have set up linux router with celeron j1900 processor, installed Arch Linux and firewalld. Connection to ISP is via PPPoE.
Firewalld is reducing maximum download speed, upload looks good:

When I stop firewalld via systemctl and do test again everythig looks good.
Even for testing purposes I didn't set any zones and policies so firewalld config is simple.
/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf  

DefaultZone=drop  
CleanupOnExit=yes  
CleanupModulesOnExit=no  
IPv6_rpfilter=strict  
IndividualCalls=no
LogDenied=all
FirewallBackend=nftables
FlushAllOnReload=yes
ReloadPolicy=INPUT:DROP,FORWARD:DROP,OUTPUT:DROP
RFC3964_IPv4=yes
NftablesFlowtable=enp4s0 enp5s0 enp6s0
NftablesCounters=no
NftablesTableOwner=yes

/etc/firewalld/direct.xml  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
  <passthrough ipv="ipv4">-t mangle -I FORWARD -p tcp --syn -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu</passthrough>
  <passthrough ipv="ipv6">-t mangle -I FORWARD -p tcp --syn -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu</passthrough>
</direct>

EDIT: I have managed it without MSS Clamping.
      I changed MTU for enp6s0 to 1512, pppoe-vlan to 1508 and for ppp0 to 1500. 
      Unfortunately this does not help with max download speed.

Network configuration is done by systemd and is also pretty simple:
/etc/systemd/network/enp4s0.network (LAN)  

[Match]
Name=enp4s0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.1/28
Address=192.168.2.1/28
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPv6LinkLocalAddressGenerationMode=stable-privacy


/etc/systemd/network/enp6s0 (WAN)

[Match]
Name=enp6s0

[Network]
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
VLAN=pppoe-vlan


/etc/systemd/network/pppoe-vlan.netdev

[NetDev]
Name=pppoe-vlan
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=6

And ppp configuration:
/etc/ppp/peers/kpn

linkname "pppoe"
updetach
plugin pppoe.so
nic-pppoe-vlan
noauth
defaultroute
defaultroute6
maxfail "5"
#usepeerdns
"persist"
+ipv6
user "*"
password "*"

This is very simple setup so I have no idea why firewalld causing this problem.
Any suggestion would be very helpful.
Regards.

Why are you clamping packets if the connection works without them?  (I am not saying this is the problem but in my experience playing with MTU's can fix and create speed issues.

@davidgo Internet connection was very slow and unusable.
According to arch wiki:
The MTU under pppoe is 1492 bytes. Most sites use an MTU of 1500. So your connection sends an ICMP 3:4 (fragmentation needed) packet, asking for a smaller MTU, but some sites have their firewall blocking that.

Maybe try removing the clamping and see what happens.   I'm not sure its totally correct that MTU under pppoe is 1492 bytes - rather that pppoe adds an 8 byte header which is encapsulated in the main packet - and if the resulting packet is larger then the packet size the interfaces can handle it will cause problems.    If things work fine without modifying the MTU you don't want to play with it - and indeed there is every possibility that the fragmentation this is causing is slowing down your session.

Also, the real maximum MTU of an ethernet packet size is often slightly (and sometimes significantly) larger then 1500 bytes - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

@davidgo Even if that's the true, you'll still need to mess with the MTU settings of the interfaces (the pppoe one and the ethernet interface "outside") to make use of it (setting them to 1500 and 1508 respectively), no? (Nevertheless, I don't think that would even help if the MTU setting on the other end of the pppoe link is 1492?)

@davidgo MTU is the max Ethernet payload size, not max frame size, and it defaults to 1500 practically everywhere, even if the frame size can sometimes grow a bit due to VLAN tags and such. (But even if the path to the ISP could carry larger frames, it's impossible for users to know exactly how much it's allowed to grow beyond the 1518-byte default L2MTU – is it 1526, or 1568, or 1596? – so 1500-byte MTU with 1518-byte frames remains the universal default.) And given a 1500-byte max payload minus 8-byte PPPoE header, the resulting space for the IP packet becomes 1492 bytes

@davidgo: As for MSS clamping, it is usually there to avoid fragmentation – TCP always tries to negotiate a segment size that exactly fits within the interface's MTU, so having the firewall 'patch' the handshake for a smaller MSS will lead to smaller packets and less fragmentation. (Though in OP's case, it's the same machine so TCP ought to be already aware of the ppp0 interface's lower MTU... manual clamping is only needed on routers, when clients are unaware of the router doing PPPoE.)

@Andrzej: What I'm really curious about though, is what sort of CPU load you see during the speed test... a celeron j1900 looks like it ought to be able to handle 1 Gbps, but the more firewall rules are added (and firewalld definitely adds some of its own), the more CPU it needs per packet, etc.

@grawity_u1686  I don't disagree, but if the connection is working fine without messing with MTU what benefit does clamping have?

I have managed it without MSS Clamping. Based on this: link i changed MTU for enp6s0 to 1512, pppoe-vlan to 1508 and for ppp0 to 1500. Unfortunately this does not help with max download speed. What weird is: speed test on router is max around 325 Mbps but on my desktop is around 500 Mbps so I really don't know what is going on.

@grawity_u1686 With firewalld enabled "1,25" cores are used, one 100% and around 25% second core. Without firewalld is different: one core 100%, second and third around 35%.

@grawity_u1686 Maybe you have right about hardware issue. I just installed everything on AMD A8 processor and I have almost 1Gbps with firewalld running.

@davidgo: Clamping has zero benefit when done on the same host that makes the connection (like in the specific example with OP running a speedtest on the same system), as that host already knows that packets will be routed over its own interface with lower MTU and will negotiate a lower TCP MSS accordingly.

@davidgo: On the other hand, when you have two separate devices – a router that has a lower-MTU PPPoE interface, and a host that connects through a 1500-MTU ethernet and is unaware of anything else – then the host will negotiate a TCP MSS suitable for its local 1500-byte MTU even though the "path MTU" is lower, resulting in a lot of fragmentation... or even complete connection hangs, if ICMP PMTUD packets are blocked. Especially in the latter case, having the router do MSS handshake clamping can be mandatory for connections to certain sites (e.g. the Windows Update CDN...) to work at all.


I have set up linux router with celeron j1900 processor

My main suspicion is that a Celeron J1900 is not fast enough to handle 1 Gbps over PPPoE with the added load of checking a bunch of firewall rules for every packet. It appears to be an Atom-based CPU, which were low-end even in their time; even more so given that you say in comments that the speed test consumes 100% of one core even without firewalld.
(The firewalld website claims that NftablesFlowtable is supposed to have higher performance than traditional Linux conntrack flow-tracking... but that may still be offset by everything else that firewalld's base ruleset does.)
Though it's unclear how much of that CPU usage is due to the packet forwarding and how much is due to the speedtest app itself. It could be that the Celeron is capable of routing 1Gbps when it has no other load, but gets overwhelmed when you run additional software on it.
You seem to have a different "Ookla speedtest" app than the one I found on Debian; the latter is a major CPU hog but I don't know whether that also applies to your version. Either way though, in addition to upgrading the CPU, I'd suggest trying different "speed test" tools – not only for the Internet connection, but also to check whether it can handle 1Gbps locally as well.
(For comparison, I ran a few tests on a Xeon system from 2007, and the Debian speedtest-cli app reached ~450% CPU at certain times, whereas iperf3 -P4 between two local systems only needed ~7% of one core.)

there's multiple speed test apps, with the official one being both the most recent I know of. https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli is what I'm running and looks identical to what OP is running. In my experience, it tends to give the 'best' benchmarks, is slightly more efficient, and gives near line speeds on the 4th gen core i3 ULT  I run as a browser/

That one seems to run at ~13% CPU during the download test on the same 2007 Xeon (with ~910 Mbps results). For an Atom CPU it's probably still a significant extra load on top of the IP routing and nftables.

I agree to your answer. I have installed OpenWRT on this machine and speed test get ~810 Mbps but LuCI was inaccessible. Single "click" get result after speed test was finished. Thank you for you answer.

I have final comment for this question. After long waiting I received router with i3-N305 processor. Difference is HUGE. With all rules enabled speed test gets full (well, almost full) 1Gbps with only one core 17% load, so there was definitely hardware problem. Thanks all for commenting and answering. Regards.
